# Сноска, относящаяся к последнему слову вопросительного предложения

Tags: пунктуация, сноски

Правильно ли я понимаю, что если сноска относится только к последнему слову вопросительного предложения, а не ко всему предложению, то знак сноски всё равно ставится после вопросительного знака? У [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=181#pp181) говорится так:

> 2. Вопросительный/восклицательный знак, многоточие и закрывающие кавычки ставятся перед знаком сноски, чтобы показать, что отсылка относится ко всему предложению...

Так как у меня сноска не относится ко всему предложению, я сомневаюсь в положении её знака. Возьмём предложение, например:

*Так вы сегодня подстрелили вальдшнепа?*

Будет ли верно написать так, если сноска относится только к слову *вальдшнеп*:

*Так вы сегодня подстрелили вальдшнепа?<sup>1</sup>*

Comment: *Чтобы показать, что отсылка относится ко всему предложению*? А есть цель показать?

Comment: @shampar, есть цель показать отношение только к последнему слову, что ясно сказано. Если вы перейдёте по ссылке на Розенталя в моём вопросе, то увидите, что в первом пункте как раз таки идёт речь об отсылках, относящихся к слову или к группе слов, но там нет информации о вопросительном, восклицательном знаках или многоточии. Точка вот (кроме случая, когда она обозначает сокращение) всегда, насколько я поняла, ставится после сноски, вне зависимости от того, к чему сноска относится. Поэтому есть сомнения.

Comment: Если такой цели нет, то вопрос становится праздным.